# is there a way to run a function every time a directive is showed?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a directive that generate it own data, this data needs to be processed after every x seconds but it should stop when I go out of the view

I have added in my directive

```
myRecursiveFunction = $interval(myfunction, 2000)
```

and in my controller

```
$interval.cancel(myRecursiveFunction)
```

it works complete ok the first time I go into the view and when I go out, but I can't find the way to retrigger this function every time this directive gets showed. Is there a way to do this?

**Edit:**

here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Saninn/wnkcnjw6/

Comment: Define "directive gets showed".

Comment: Every time I go into a view with this directive inside.

Comment: can you provide fiddle?

Comment: put the code in the directive...not complicated. Use `$destroy` event to cancel it

Comment: @ram1993 I added a fiddle to my question.

Comment: @charlietfl I can't find the way to do it.